# How to change the caret of the Gnome Terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal

How do you change the text-cursor/caret in Terminal to block, I-Beam, or underline.

Comment: Gnome terminal or some other kind of GUI? Maybe the tty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to the GUI method, you can also change the cursor shape from the command-line:

```
$ gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/cursor_shape <VALUE>
```

The possible values are "**block**" to use a block cursor, "**ibeam**" to use a vertical line cursor, or "**underline**" to use an underline cursor.

To get the current value:

```
$ gconftool-2 --get /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/cursor_shape
block
```

Comment: you already have my up-vote for the step-by-step GUI method ;)

Comment: Note: This changes the caret not only in the current terminal, but also in all other current and future gnome-terminal tabs of the same profile, just as if you opened the graphical preferences editor and switched it there.

Comment: @egmont Indeed, I've just read your answer. Now depending if it has to be persistent or not, we have the choice. Thanks

Answer (score 16):

In recent versions of gnome-terminal, you can use the following escape sequences to change the cursor:

- `\e[0 q` or `\e[ q`: reset to whatever's defined in the profile settings
- `\e[1 q`: blinking block
- `\e[2 q`: steady block
- `\e[3 q`: blinking underline
- `\e[4 q`: steady underline
- `\e[5 q`: blinking I-beam
- `\e[6 q`: steady I-beam

You can print these by e.g. `echo -ne '\e[5 q'`.

This has the advantage/disadvantage (based on your use case) compared to the `gconftool` method that it influences the given tab only, and not all the tabs that use the given profile.

Comment: This looks awesome! Unfortunately, I can't use it (running `gnome-terminal` 3.14.1). Is there anything I should do to enable this? (it does work in `xterm`)

Comment: This feature is available since vte-0.40 which officially pairs with gnome-terminal-3.16 (although you can probably upgrade your vte only and keep gnome-terminal-3.14).

Comment: Great, let's upgrade then. Cheers!

Comment: great answer! I followed these instructions to get gnome-terminal 3.16 http://askubuntu.com/a/625250/114821

Comment: NB: if you're using tmux, you'll probably need to tell tmux how to reset the cursor shape by adding something like this to your .tmux.conf, or the first sequence won't work: `set -ga terminal-overrides ",*256color*:Se=\\E[0 q"`

Answer (score 6):

To change your text-cursor/caret:

1. *Open up* **Terminal**.
2. *Right click* the terminal window.
3. *Hover* your mouse over the option **Profiles**.
4. *Select* **Profile Prefrences**.

As seen here:

[image: Just a terminal window]

5.Here you will find the option, **Cursor Shape**.

[image: Cusor shape]

6.Enjoy using Terminal with a different Caret.

Comment: where is the cursor shape?