# What does this bash escape sequence mean?

Tags: command-line, bash

I've searched for a way to change terminal title and found this bash command:

```
echo -ne "\033]0;NEW_TITLE\007"
```

It works as it have to, but i'm now interested in what this "magic symbols" mean and how it works.

Comment: It shows nothing for me on Bash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That uses an [XTerm control sequence](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Operating-System-Controls). `echo` with `-e` interprets certain sequences in the string given, in this case `\033` became <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and `\007` is the ASCII bell character (see [`man 7 ascii`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man7/ascii.7.html)).

An <kbd>Esc</kbd> (represented as `^]`) followed by `]` is, in XTerm parlance, an [Operating System Control code](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Operating-System-Controls). Terminals which support it interpret it as given in the above link:

```
OSC Ps ; Pt ST
OSC Ps ; Pt BEL
          Set Text Parameters.  For colors and font, if Pt is a "?", the
          control sequence elicits a response which consists of the con-
          trol sequence which would set the corresponding value.  The
          dtterm control sequences allow you to determine the icon name
          and window title.
            Ps = 0  -> Change Icon Name and Window Title to Pt.
            Ps = 1  -> Change Icon Name to Pt.
            Ps = 2  -> Change Window Title to Pt.
```

`OSC` being `^]]`, the `Ps` in this case is `0`, which sets `Pt`, in this case `NEW_TITLE`, as the terminal title.

Related:

- [What do the different colors mean in ls?](https://askubuntu.com/q/17299/158442)
- [How to change the caret of the Gnome Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/504240/158442)