# gnome-terminal vim strange characters

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, vim

I'm getting very odd characters (001B in a block, which apparently is escape?) in vim when I enter a newline, and sometimes when I switch to normal mode.

You can see the result here:

[image: Screenshot of odd characters]

What's odd is that it behaves normally in gvim/macvim/iTerm2 vim, but not gnome-terminal. I'm using base16-shell to get base16-ocean, and the colortest succeeds.

Here is my corresponding vimrc:

[.vimrc](https://github.com/mjedmonds/.dotfiles/blob/master/vim/.vimrc)

Comment: @Terrance - Worked fine for me.

Comment: @AndroidDev Glad you got it working.  Mine was giving me inaccessible possibly because it was a link to a dropbox which might be blocked here.

Comment: @Terrance *<shrug>*

Comment: Have you tried it in any other terminal ? Open `xterm`  and try there.

Comment: @mjedmonds Is this `gnome-terminal` on OS X or macOS?

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex gnome-terminal on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @Serg Problem doesn't exist in xterm (but I would still prefer to use gnome-terminal, everything else looks bad in xterm)

Comment: Esc is usually used to start an ANSI escape code. It looks like both Esc and P are being shown. According to [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), `ESC P` means "Controls a device. In xterm, uses of this sequence include defining User-Defined Keys, and requesting or setting Termcap/Terminfo data." Not sure why they're not being handled properly.

Comment: @mjedmonds you don't necessarily have to use `xterm`. This just proves that the issue isn't vim, but with `gnome-terminal`. You can always switch to `terminator` or `konsole` - there's plenty of choice for terminal emulators. As far as `gnome-terminal`, can you take a look at your profile settings, and let me know if they are same or different form what I have ?  screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/sX1Ze

Comment: @Serg Changing to `terminator` won't solve this problem, it uses the same terminal emulation widget (`vte`) as gnome-terminal, hence has the same emulation features and bugs.

Comment: You're probably hitting gnome-terminal (vte) bug http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=403130. You could track down what is the escape sequence printed at your setup that's not supported by vte, and modify your setup so that it's not printed.

Comment: It's the t_SI and t_EI definition in your vimrc around line 134 that print ESC P as well as that 50;CursorShape stuff which are not supported by gnome-terminal. I don't know what ESC P is supposed to do. Changing the cursor shape is supported by recent gnome-terminal (vte) versions, although via different escape sequences than this 50;CursorShape (see http://askubuntu.com/a/620306/398785).

Comment: @egmont bingo! thank you and others. A solution for the vimrc is here: [updated vimrc](https://github.com/mjedmonds/.dotfiles/commit/41c1d4639d7b2b047d260602f27a80695cf73f9c)

Answer (score 1):

Per @egmont, Solution is to update vim's cursors to avoid gnome-terminals' [vte bug](http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=403130).

See solution at my updated vimrc: https://github.com/mjedmonds/.dotfiles/commit/41c1d4639d7b2b047d260602f27a80695cf73f9c

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mjedmonds for the original solution.  I found it quite good for Terminator but still had a couple of buggy screens (vim from ptipython for one) and issues with the initial cursor.  So I removed the apple filters and added a little - potential users will probably benefit from comparing the two.

```
" Solve extra characters on vim screens in terminator in Linux
" Enable different cursors based on the mode from
" https://github.com/mjedmonds/dotfiles/commit/41c1d4639d7b2b047d260602f27a80695cf73f9c
" Information on cursors to complete it from
" https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Change_cursor_shape_in_different_modes"

if has("autocmd")
  au BufNewFile,VimEnter,BufEnter,InsertLeave * 
    \ silent execute '!echo -ne "\e[2 q"' | redraw!
  au InsertEnter,InsertChange *
    \ if v:insertmode == 'i' | 
    \   silent execute '!echo -ne "\e[6 q"' | redraw! |
    \ elseif v:insertmode == 'r' |
    \   silent execute '!echo -ne "\e[4 q"' | redraw! |
    \ endif
  au VimLeave * silent execute '!echo -ne "\e[ q"' | redraw!
endif

let &t_SI = "\<Esc>P\<Esc>\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7\<Esc>\\"
let &t_SR = "\<Esc>P\<Esc>\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=2\x7\<Esc>\\"
let &t_EI = "\<Esc>P\<Esc>\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=2\x7\<Esc>\\"
```