# How can I change the cursor in vim depending if I'm in insert mode or normal mode?

Tags: command-line, vim, cursor

I'm used to working on GVim, but I want to make most of vim+tmux too. Therefore I have decided to switch to vim. But in vim the cursor style does not change depending on the mode.

I use zsh and gnome terminal.

I have tried this answer: [How to make cursor change from thin line to block based on normal or insert mode in Console Vim on Gnome Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42663/how-to-make-cursor-change-from-thin-line-to-block-based-on-normal-or-insert-mode)

```
if has("autocmd")
  au InsertEnter * silent execute "!gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/cursor_shape ibeam"
  au InsertLeave * silent execute "!gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/cursor_shape block"
  au VimLeave * silent execute "!gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/cursor_shape ibeam"
endif
```

but it changes the cursor globally.

I have also tried [this plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4403), but it hasn't worked either. (How can I check if the plugin is working?)

Comment: According to [the current docs of that plugin](https://github.com/jszakmeister/vim-togglecursor/blob/master/doc/togglecursor.txt#L26), it needs VTE > 0.39, which is not available for [any version of Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libvte9).  Can you try with any of the other terminal emulators mentioned (`rxvt`, `konsole`)?

Comment: See [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Configuring_the_cursor) , "Comments "section, after "See also"

Comment: Please don't cross-post questions; you already asked it here http://stackoverflow.com/q/34251566/1439843

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it [has been posted](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34251566/1081936) (and answered) on another site in the SE network.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42118416/52817

Answer (score 0):

Two different options are listed here:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251566/how-can-i-change-the-cursor-style-in-vim-depending-if-im-in-insert-mode-or-norm
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488683/how-do-i-change-the-vim-cursor-in-insert-normal-mode

.vimrc files with good comments will help you too, e.g. https://github.com/thoughtbot/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc

Comment: While your answer is valid, you should provide the steps here, links and their content can change and then your answer would be a dead end. You still can refer the links as sources.

Comment: @Videonauth sorry, I was not sure if it could be a duplicate if the question were asked on a site of the same network - so I choose to put the links. I'm waiting 15rep to be able to comment instead of answering.

Comment: @ponsfrilus It's  a cross-post, the first question you link is also asked by Jonas, and it (sort of) duplicates the second question you linked. So I flagged for duplicate at SO, and asked for moderator attention on this question.

Comment: yes, I am sorry for that. At the time of posting I did not know those websites are so well connected. I just thought I ask at two places to reach out to more people.

Comment: @Jonas No problem, it can happen ;)